# Confirming Navigation in a React ES6 project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, listener, react-router

I am using React and React Router with ES6 classes, and trying to find the best solution to prevent the user from leaving a page with unsaved changes in a form.

In componentDidMount, I have added the following (mostly based on https://github.com/mjackson/history/blob/master/docs/ConfirmingNavigation.md):

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'    
browserHistory.listenBefore(function (location) {
   if (this.state.isDirty)
       return 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?'
})

this.history = useBeforeUnload(createHistory)()
this.history.listenBeforeUnload( () => {
    if (this.state.isDirty)
       return "You have pending changes."
})
```

Two questions:

1) This works but is this a correct way of achieving the goal (user attempting to leave page while unsaved changed)? In particular the fact that I am creating a new history for beforeunload.
2) When leaving the page, how do I remove the listeners? I can see for instance that every time I reenter the page a new listener for the beforeunload event is added.

Comment: you can remove them by leaving the page.

Comment: yeah, the listeners wont persist.

Comment: I must have missed something because in the Before Unload case I can inspect the web page and see the beforeunload listeners adding up (easy to fix if I use for instance window.add/removeEventListener). For the hook added to the browserHistory, I added a console.log that shows the listener getting fired even after having left the page... I suppose it is because I am using the browserHistory from react-router...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Router 4 -- listen to route actions and programmatically continue/stop routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50546624/react-router-4-listen-to-route-actions-and-programmatically-continue-stop-rou)