# React Router 4 -- listen to route actions and programmatically continue/stop routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

this is my scenario:

- I have a user form where user inputs details
- I want to create a confirmation message when user tries to leave current page i.e. "Hey you have unsaved changes"
- My component is a component specified by my route so it has access to match, location, route, and history.
- I am aware if the listen and block function of history but how do we achieve this? can we call these function in a life cycle somewhere or do you guys have any other idea to achieve this?

references:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#listening

https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#blocking-transitions

my question:

- How to listen to router when user leaves current page/route? (you get the point)
- programmatically allow user to continue or not

Comment: ...and what have you tried?

Comment: Add a code snippet. If you happen to use 'redux' write a middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a specific component in `react-router` just for that specific purpose: `<Prompt>`

Quoting from the [readme](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Prompt):

> Used to prompt the user before navigating away from a page. When your
> application enters a state that should prevent the user from
> navigating away (like a form is half-filled out), render a `<Prompt>`.

The `<Prompt>` has the `when` and the `message` props. The prompt is displayed when the user tries to navigate away and `when` is set to true. So, you can have a function set some bool variable to true/false according to your requirement and pass it as a prop to the `<Prompt>`.

For example:

```
//your component where you get user input

state = {
    name: "",
};

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Prompt
            when={!!this.state.name} /* triggers the display of prompt */ 
                                  /*(checks if this.state.name is set)*/
            message={location => `You have unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to go to ${location.pathname}?`}
          />
          <div>Nice looking profile! What's your name?</div>
          <input value={this.state.name} onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

[image: Sample prompt]

[Codesandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/browniefed/tmp/tree/reactRouterEditPrompt/) (not mine)

Find the tutorial [here](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/46/Prevent-Navigation-with-the-React-Router-Prompt-Component-When-Data-is-Being-Edited)

Check the `<Prompt>` documentation here: [docs](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Prompt)

Comment: Thanks for your well written answer! Didn't notice that from the docs, although it would have been cool if we could render a custom component and make an algorithm to return true/false.